# Changed permissions of /usr

Tags: permissions

Being the noob that I am, I seemed to have changed the permissions of /usr not knowing the consequence of that action.  That's pretty much locked me out of my system, not allowing me to do anything.

Reading up more on this, it sounds like a very bad thing that will probably cause me to have to reinstall my OS.  Is there a way I can fix this in any way without reinstalling or at least saving my settings?  If I have to redo all my server settings again I might cry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to revert the change using

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr
```

---

**Edit:** If you haven't changed the permission recursively before, **don't** do it now!

---

If that is not possible, shut down the the raspberry and mount the SD card on another computer to perform the change.

In that case, please **don't** use the path above!

But do **not** wipe the system until you are really sure it is fully broken.

Comment: What command would I use once my sd was mounted to another computer?  Same permissions with a different file path?

Comment: It still would be `chmod` with `-R` to be sure that it is recursive and `755` (that is `rwxr-xr-x`) but you have to use another path, because the `/usr` of your SD card is now mounted somewhere else. Otherwise, you would mess around with the other computer too ;) Good luck!

Comment: Do you think I could jus boot of a CD into Ubuntu and do this?  I don't currently have any linux distros installed on a proper computer.

Comment: I would give it a try! If that doesn't work, put the SD card aside and do it at a friends PC. Just don't kill it without saving all the setups you have spent so much time on.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada `-R` probably is not necessary and maybe even harmful. If you haven't used it before, better don't use it now.

Comment: i did change it recursively, so ill probably have to change it back the same way

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem like it wants to work.  I'm thinking of just reimaging the card and starting over; I guess the more practise I have the better I'll get, haha ;)